# Windows Live Mail will not open

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail

Had 2011 fine for over a year, then last week it just hung on startup - little circle and says "starting".

In task manager it is open as a process, but not as an app. I tried offline, reinstalled, repaired Live Essentials, did all win updates, installed 2912, repaired essentials again, ran fixkey.reg, did MS authenticity check, and removed all mail from folders all with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.